# Durandal tries to access view from viewmodel folder

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal

I have a compose binding and when durandal tries to find the view it looks under `app/viewmodels` instead of `app/views`

VM looks like this

```
define(["fields/fieldClosures"], function (fields) {
    var ctor = function(opt) {
        this.value = opt.value;
    };

    return fields.readonly.default = ctor;
});
```

View that uses compose binding

```
<div data-name="fields">
    <div data-bind="css: { 'has-error': hasError }" class="form-group">
        <label data-name="label" data-bind="attr: { 'for': id }" class="col-lg-3 control-label"></label>
        <div data-name="field" class="col-lg-9"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`data-name="field"` gets translated into data-bind="compose: field" by a convention over configuration library for KO. If I use the standard compose binding directly I get the same result

**update:** 
Path to VM \App\viewmodels\form\fields\readonly\text.js

field is a member holding the reference to the VM

This is the VM that holds the *field* member

```
define(["fields/fieldClosures",
    "fields/readonly/text", //Need to find a better way to load all view models with requirejs without specifying them all here 
    "fields/readonly/date",
    "fields/readonly/number"], function (fields) {
    function factory(closure, opt) {
        for (var index in closure) {
            var model = closure[index];
            if (model.can && model.can(opt == null ? null : ko.unwrap(opt.value))) {
                return model;
            }
        }

        return closure.default;
    }

    var id = 0;
    var ctor = function(label, value, canEdit, options) {
        this.id = "control-" + id++;
        this.label = label;
        var opt = { value: value, label: label, options: options };
        var closure = canEdit ? fields.editors : fields.readonly;
        var model = factory(closure, opt);

        this.field = new model(opt);

        this.field.id = this.id;
        this.hasError = canEdit ? ko.computed(this.getHasError, this) : null;
    };

    ctor.prototype = {
        getHasError: function() {
            return this.field.value.isValid && !this.field.value.isValid();
        }
    };

    return ctor;
});
```

useConvention is turned on for the viewLocator and other views are working, its just this view that wont load correctly. Well it does not work for any views that are loaded in the above fashion

1. "fields/readonly/text"
2. "fields/readonly/date"
3. "fields/readonly/number"

The references are created with the a factory, but the contructors are injected with requirejs like normal

**update**

fields is a path added at start doing

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'text': '../Scripts/text',
        'durandal': '../Scripts/durandal',
        'plugins': '../Scripts/durandal/plugins',
        'transitions': '../Scripts/durandal/transitions',
        "fields": "viewmodels/form/fields"
    }
});
```

Comment: Show a short example using the standard compose binding, and also tell us what the module ID for the VM you showed is.

Comment: `<div data-bind="compose: field" class="col-lg-9"></div>` what do you mean with moduel id?

Comment: The file name of the viewmodel you showed. Also, what's `field` set to (that syntax indicates that it's an observable that should be holding either a module ID for a VM or a view name)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you enabled `useConvention` on the `viewLocator`? If not, by default durandal will look for the view at the same path as the viewModel. Here's the code from the `viewLocator` which does the translation:

```
convertModuleIdToViewId: function(moduleId) {
    return moduleId;
}
```

If you tell the `viewLocator` to `useConvention` it will force the view/viewModels setup that you're referring to. Here's the relevant source code (trimmed for brevity):

```
useConvention: function(modulesPath, viewsPath, areasPath) {
    modulesPath = modulesPath || 'viewmodels';
    viewsPath = viewsPath || 'views';

    var reg = new RegExp(escape(modulesPath), 'gi');

    this.convertModuleIdToViewId = function (moduleId) {
        return moduleId.replace(reg, viewsPath);
    };
}
```

The alternative would be to configure the view locator with your own implementation of `convertModuleIdToViewId`, and hook it up early in your application's lifecycle (e.g. at the application entry point):

```
var configureViewLocator = function () {
    var viewModelsRegex = /viewmodels/gi;

    viewLocator.convertModuleIdToViewId = function (moduleId) {
        return moduleId.replace(viewModelsRegex, "views");
    };
};
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Its based on the starter kit so yes its turned on, plus it works for all other VM's / Views. It's just this view thats not working.

Comment: Is the full path to your view really `fields/readonly/number`? Durandal is looking for `viewModels` in the path which it will substitute with `views`. If you have set up some sort of alias in require (which I suspect you have based on your module imports) then Durandal won't be able to resolve the `viewModel` part of the module id. Try debugging through the `convertModuleIdToViewId` method and you should be able to see what's wrong.